# what's the size of arr[0]?

Tags: c

Below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double arr[0];
    double arr_one[1];
    printf("%d, %d",sizeof(arr[0]), sizeof(arr_one[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
8,8
```

I want to know why `arr[0]`, `arr_one[1]` have the same size.

Comment: `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[1000]` - any of those would be a `double`, and therefore of the same size. What were you expecting?

Comment: `arr[0]` is illegal except in a few very special contexts (which are different in C and in C++).

Comment: g++ compiles it happily. The weirdness of the 0-size array is a separate issue from the size of theoretical elements *of* that array.

Comment: An array cannot have size 0 in standard C.

Comment: @Lundin And in C++, it can only have a size 0 in a new expression.

Answer (score 5):

When you index the array with `[]` the type is that of the array *element*, in this case `double` for both arrays. Without the indexing (i.e., `sizeof(arr)`), the type would be that of the array.

Comment: Note that there is a separate issue in the code with `double arr[0]` being an array of zero size, but on compilers where such an array is allowed the _element type_ of the array is still `double` - hence the `sizeof` result. `sizeof` does not access the element or require it to exist (e.g., `sizeof(*nullptr)` is likewise allowed).

Answer (score 2):

You're not even looking at `arr_one`, nor `arr` really.  You're using the array `arr` to get the size of it's elements (`double`) which, of course, are the same.

Comment: I assume you mean `double`, not `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Zero-sized arrays are not allowed, so that code shouldn't compile.

If you have a compiler that accepts it as a non-standard extension, then the result `sizeof` only depends on the type of the expression; in this case `double`. The expression is not evaluated (so it doesn't matter if it involves an out-of-bounds array access or other undefined behaviour), and its type is the same regardless of whether or not it would have a well-defined value.

If you were to ask for the size of the array, `sizeof(arr)`, then that would depend on how the compiler chose to deal with non-standard zero-sized arrays. Being non-standard, there is no standard specification of their size.

Answer (score 1):

An array is just a piece of memory, all elements are behind each other.

Consider the next array of char rather then doubles:

```
char* text = "Hello World!";

char* begin = text;
char* end = text + strlen( text ) - 1;

while( begin++ < end )
    printf( *begin );
```

Notice the `char* begin = text` or the text declartor itself for the same matter. In the printf you are dereferencing the begin pointer to the first element `*begin = *text = 'H'`.

When declaring an array, the smallest piece is always allocated, which is the size of the type.

The next could/would be equal to `char text[0]` but then compilable.

```
char* text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

they are the same because you are looking at the size of the first element of two arrays.

try `sizeof(arr)` and `sizeof(arr_one)`, which is the size of the array.

Comment: Please do not [edit question content to fix code](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5775012).

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof() double` type is 8 that's why you are getting 8,8 . array `arr[0]` always refers as double type subscripted variable  and `arry_one[1]` is also refers to a `double` type value so output 8,8 .